# Hibernate @Id and oracle Unique constraint

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Can I use an hibernate entity with @Id on a unique constraint instead of a primary key on oracle databases? Also will it be JPA compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a bit strange, but seems possible:
http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Id:

*The field or property to which the Id annotation is applied **should be one of the following types**: any Java primitive type; any primitive wrapper type; String; java.util.Date; java.sql.Date; java.math.BigDecimal; java.math.BigInteger.*

But be aware:
(1) E.g. in Oracle UNIQUE does not imply NOT NULL, you have to ensure this by your own.
(2) You can't use a FOREIGN KEY constraint in your DB.
(3) You have to be careful with Id generation (http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/GeneratedValue) if you want to insert new entities (not only read existing ones).
(4) If you insert a new entity, you have to generate a value for the DB id.

And that are only a few disadvantages that came quickly to my mind ...

Comment: about 2) In oracle you can use a foreign key against constraints, and in this sense use FK's also against unique constraints. but furthermore thanks for the explanation